# SQL - Selecting rows with Max date1 for each column with higher than zero QTY in each different date2 column

Tags: sql

could you please help me with following SQL script? Our supplier sends us files with order on daily basis, where they for one material number can have multiple Delivery Dates, and he often sends updates for same delivery date, sometimes lowering QTY of delivery to zero, raising or lowering the QTY..

in my DB, I have MaterialNr, date of order (basicaly date of QTY update), and the Expected delivery date..
For making life easier, we need to filter out:
Each Material and every different DeliveryDate where MAX OrderDate has not QTY = 0,
that means if the last update for any DeliveryDate was 0 (and there was no other Order later with some higher QTY), then leave that DeliveryDate out and search for next..

ps: both date formats are like (yyyyMMdd)

Example table:

| MaterialNr | OrderDate | DeliveryDate | QTY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20201201 | 20210430 | 60 |
| 1 | 20210101 | 20210430 | 0 |
| 1 | 20210130 | 20210515 | 80 |
| 2 | 20201201 | 20210430 | 10 |
| 2 | 20201201 | 20210630 | 50 |
| 2 | 20210101 | 20210430 | 20 |
| 2 | 20210101 | 20210630 | 0 |
| 2 | 20210101 | 20210515 | 30 |
| 2 | 20210216 | 20210430 | 40 |
| 3 | 20201201 | 20210425 | 10 |
| 3 | 20210101 | 20210425 | 10 |

Expected result:

| MaterialNr | OrderDate | DeliveryDate | QTY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20210130 | 20210515 | 80 |
| 2 | 20210216 | 20210430 | 40 |
| 2 | 20210101 | 20210515 | 30 |
| 3 | 20210101 | 20210425 | 10 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just find the maximum date of each `0` for each material.  Then choose rows above that:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             max(case when qty = 0 then deliverydate end) over (partition by materialnr) as date_0
      from t
     ) t
where date_0 is null or
      deliverydate > date_0
```

You can also do this with `not exists`.  The logic is that you want all rows where there is no `0` afterwards:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.materialnr = t.materialnr and
                        t2.qty = 0 and
                        t2.deliverydate >= t.deliverydate
                 );
```

Comment: thank you, i will let you know how it worked for me in about hour :)

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using window functions:

```
SELECT * FROM ( 
    SELECT *
           , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MaterialNr ,DeliveryDate ORDER BY orderdate DESC) rn
FROM dbo.yourtable ) tt
WHERE tt.rn = 1
AND QTY <> 0
```

Comment: Thank you guys, Im gonna try it in hour or so, ill let you know how it worked for me :)